# macro to "save as" and don't open the saved document

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro that "Save As" a copy of the excel doc.

```
Sub STEP3SaveAs()
    Application.GetSaveAsFilename
End Sub
```

BUT, every time I "Save As", I land on the doc I just saved...

I need assistance with a Macro that will "Save As", and leave me on the doc that I was working on.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `GetSaveAsFilename` does not save at all. This just shows a dialog to choose a filename, but does not save it.

You can use the [Workbook.SaveCopyAs Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-savecopyas-method-excel) to save a copy of your actual workbook.

```
Public Sub SaveCopy()
    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename 'choose filename

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(Filename)
End Sub
```

Comment: Will test this one quick and revert back. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `.SaveAs` twice, thus it would return you the original workbook. The `ThisWorkbook.FullName` is a way to obtain the path:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim saveName As String
    Dim oldName  As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        oldName = .FullName
        saveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename            
        .SaveAs saveName
        .SaveAs oldName
    End With

End Sub
```